# Ubuntu-Core Desktop/Raspberry Pi

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I have "snapped" Core22-desktop to an RPI but how is is executed?

Comment: What do you mean by "snapped" - the Core22  is installed as a snap package? What do you mean exactly by "how is it executed"? Are you looking for technical details on what Ubuntu Core is and how it works or how you run Ubuntu Core 22? Please edit your original question and add more details / context.

Comment: I am using the Ubuntu-Core on a Raspberry Pi 4 v7 and have installed Core22-desktop. The Core22-desktop is installed using snap.  The documentation ends with the installation with no further instructions.  So my question is does this have to built as a standalone image or is it built into the existing Ubuntu-Core already in place?  sudo snap install core22-desktop --edge

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really usable already... It is my understanding that this is a development snap, gearing towards future versions of Ubuntu for the immutable desktop (see e.g. https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-core-desktop). I think what you installed is not production-ready software.

Comment: @JamesROwens Please edit the details from your comment into your question